# C++ range iterator algorithm to collect result

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, iterator-range

I have written a function to collect the result of a boost iterator range. Here it is:

```
template<typename Output, typename SinglePassRange>
Output collect(const SinglePassRange & rng)
{
    Output r;
    boost::range::copy(rng, std::inserter(r, boost::begin(r)));
    return r;
}
```

It is rather convenient:

```
return collect<std::vector<int>>(ints | filtered(even) | transformed(add1));
```

This seems like something that really ought to exist already, but I could not find it. (Not to mention it would be nice to "deduce" the return type somehow, which would be a feature more likely found in a standard implementation.)

Does anyone know of a function that behaves like this?

Comment: auto collect(const SinglePassRange& rng) -> decltype(yourList) ?

Comment: Would that translate to `auto collect(const SinglePassRange& rng) -> decltype(Output)`?

Comment: I think it would translate to: -> decltype(boost::range::range_value<rng>::type)

Comment: The return type cannot be deduced, because I can ask for whatever type I want as long as I can insert into it.